# Extract JSON from HTML <script> tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, http, parsing, xmlhttprequest

A web page has JSON inside its html tree within script tag. I need to extract that JSON object and manipulate with it as JSON object. Please advice how can I achieve it.
I am trying to do it in such way:

```
var url = 'https://indooroopillyshopping.com.au/stores/'
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
console.log("sending request to ", url);
//WAIT
xhr.send();
console.log("receive respond from ", url);

var data = xhr.responseText;
var json = data.match(/\[{"id":"836","title":"Acutherapy".*/g); //I need an object window.STORES = [{}]
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringJson);//catch an error
```

I also tried to do in such way:

```
var json = data.match(/{"id":"836","title":"Acutherapy".*/g);
var newjson = json[0].substring(0, json[0].length-2);//remove space and square bracket at the end
var stringJson = JSON.stringify(newjson);
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(stringJson)
console.log(parsedJson[0].id)//I cannot access JSON with dot notation as it acts like a string (object but not [Object object])
```

All I need is to convert json string to json object to have access to it's keys and values.

Comment: It's probably better practice to load json through a http request then a script tag and it tends to parse better that way if it's a valid json string

Comment: And I think you want too look at the documentation on xmlhttprequest because I believe it has event handlers. Also by default xml requests are designed to receive xml not json which is probably a large portion of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I've found a solution by myself. I couldn't parse the extracted json as it was ';' at the end of the string, as string extracted as '[{}];'. And I it should look like - '[{}]'. maybe to someone this information will be useful

```
var data = xhr.responseText;
var json = data.match(/\[{"id":"836","title":"Acutherapy".*/g);

var newjson = json[0].substring(0, json[0].length-1);
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(newjson)
console.log(parsedJson[1].id); //668
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [JSON.parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx) (supported in most browsers) it as simple as this example:

```
var json = '{"key1":1,"key2":2}',
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);   
console.log(parsedJson.key1);
```